# Clickable links in e-mails (google,yahoo)

Tags: html, email

So I'm working on the email verification part of my website. And I came across an unexpected error.

When I send an email to a user. I write it like this but for some reason the links aren't clickable.

How can I make my emails have clickable links?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="www.google.com">I'm a link to somewhere</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That link is a local link; for instance, if that page is on `http://localhost/index.html`, if you click it it would go to `http://localhost/www.google.com`. Add `http://` to the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should had : http:// to your link.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">I'm a link to somewhere</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you dont it sends you to:
http://www.mywebstie.com/www.google.com 
Of course mywebsite is just a exemple. 
Have a Nice Day ;).